# How to get email body in plain text in python 3.x

Tags: python, email

I have seen several question like this but none of their solution seemed to work for me. I have an email dataset, I read them as a text, afterwards I need the body only as a plain text. I have tried multiple ways but I always get something like this (part of one of the printed emails):

Some of the functions I used:

```
def getEmailMsg(mail):
    msg = email.message_from_string(mail)
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            parts = part.get_payload()
            print(parts)
            return parts
```

I usually get the plain text but mostly with `<br> <p> <a>` tags, also sometimes it prints all the html.

I think I found that the problem is when the email is non-mulitpart. But I don't know how should I extract the body from non-multipart.

Comment: Can you post at least *one* of the "multiple ways" you have tried to solve this?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry, totally forgot.